# Searching for a book about a father and son who are both archers

Tags: story-identification, books

So, the book is about two boys. In the first chapter it's perspective is on one of the boys, then the next chapter is in the perspective of the other boy, and so on. One is a peasant whose father works on building the wall (I think it is the Great Wall of China), and he also has a mother and a sister I think. His father had to work extra because I think they raised the prices on something, and it was becoming harder to buy food. In one part of the book his grandmother comes over I think.

For the other boy, he is the son of a General, and I remember one of the General's good friends was a traitor or something. The General's friend had taken his daughter I think to take her somewhere safe. Anyway, the boy used to climb on the roofs and wanted to become an archer, unless that was the other boy...

There was another part where the General's son had taken an arrow for the peasant boy, and the peasant boy used a bow and arrow to knock out a lantern that would have caused a war or something. I believe both boys were also the year of the dragon.

I also remember where I think the father had to go up to do archery, but the peasant boy took his fathers place. I think it was to earn some cows or something.

The cover was white, and I think it had either a dragon or tiger on it... I cannot remember...

I vaguely remember reading how the general commented how the two boys were destined to meet (something involving the year of the dragon)

Comment: Any science fiction or fantasy element to the story?

Answer (score 2):

*[Year of the Tiger](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6012252-year-of-the-tiger)* by Alison Lloyd looks likely.

[image: Book Cover]

> In ancient China, two boys forge an unlikely alliance in an effort to become expert archers and, ultimately, to save their city from invading barbarians.
>
> A coming-of-age adventure story of two boys, the battalion commander's son Ren and noodle seller's son Hu, set during China's Han era against a backdrop of period politics and a dangerous uprising that threatens the stability of the Great Wall.

The reviews indicate that there is an archery contest and a nefarious plan. Hu is the archer, but Ren owns a bow and arrow.